# Grunt un-css ignoring the css generated by java-script

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I am new to grunt and using for the java-script and css magnification. It's just an awesome tool. After exploring the grunt few more i came across uncss module which can help a lot to improve the load time and size of the css (especially framework like bootstrap css ).

I have app in angular and php which has a classes generated by php and java-script dynamically .While running the uncss this css selector are removed from new css file generated.

I think i have install phantom-js while installing the uncss module of grunt.

Can anyone has idea how i can achieve this.

Comment: I don't think it will work for dynamic content generated by js, the walkaround may be save all the css manually. Check: https://github.com/giakki/uncss/issues/50. Hope that help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the selectors of the generated css you can use the ignore option:

```
uncss: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'dist/css/app.css': ['app/index.html']
    }
  },
  options: {
    ignore: ['#ignoredselector', '.ignoredselector']
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked for me using the url under options, but i need to go and put every url, how can i ignore putting url manually.

Comment: you can use *.php to select every .php file in the folder.